# Laravel vue.js login 419 (unknown status)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to perform a login request using axios ,the csrf is working fine ,tried adding it to the header and tried to post it with the data ,and the login process is working fine it returns the process succeed but also it fires an exception , 419 unknown status , i googled alot , all about csrf token but as mentioned it's added successfully =>

```
"_token":this.csfr,
```

[image]

[image]

so what do you think is the problem .

Comment: Post all the code where you create and send the request with the token

Answer (score 0):

< meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
< script >window.Laravel = { csrfToken: '{{ csrf_token() }}' }< /script >

add this to your blade

Comment: Please edit your answer so to follow the rules of this community. Thank you.